# Не могу заставить работать две задачи в celery параллельно

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery

У меня есть парсер данных с сайта hh.ru но для полного заполнения мне нужно запустить две задачи, но нужно чтобы они работали параллельно. Я читал что celery и так разные задачи выполняет параллельно но у меня почему-то начинает выполняться только первая

```
Файл celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery.schedules import crontab

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hh_ru_django.settings')


app = Celery('hh_ru_django')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace="CELERY")

app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'parser_hh': {
        'task': 'ads.tasks.scrape_ads',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='*/1'),
        'args': (),
    },
    'contacts_parser': {
        'task': 'ads.tasks.contacts_collector',
        'schedule': crontab(hour = '*/24'),
        'args': ()
    }
}

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

```
файл tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .scrapers import parser_hh, scrape_contacts

from celery import shared_task


url = "https://rostov.hh.ru/search/vacancy?clusters=true&enable_snippets=true&only_with_salary=true&order_by=publication_time&search_period=1&L_save_area=true&area=113&from=cluster_area&showClusters=true"


@shared_task
def scrape_ads():
    parser_hh(url)
    return


@shared_task
def contacts_collector():
    scrape_contacts()
    return
```

Comment: Когда вам нужно запускать эти задачи?

Comment: Исправил в файле celery.py, одну раз в час, другую раз в сутки. Но нужно чтобы они одновременно начали свое первое выполнение, и чтобы в дальнейшем задача которая работает раз в 24 часа не перебивала почасовую.

Comment: Замените `hour = '*/24'` на `minute=0, hour=0`